# Bypass Firewall blocking ports other than 80 and 443

Tags: ssh, firewall

Institute firewall blocking ports other than 80 and 443.

---

I want to connect to amazon ec2 and the digital ocean droplet through ssh

How to use ssh?Please provide the explanation in layman terms?

Comment: Configure the server, running the ssh demon, to use port 80 or 443

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH tunneling for bypassing firewall (http and socks)](http://superuser.com/questions/172014/ssh-tunneling-for-bypassing-firewall-http-and-socks)

Comment: I tried using corkscrew and setting up sshd on port 443 but they went in vain.

Comment: Did you try the answers in the linked question?

Comment: [firewall has blocked ssh](http://superuser.com/questions/623063/firewall-has-blocked-ssh?rq=1)

Comment: [ISP blocks the use of ssh?](http://superuser.com/questions/330223/isp-blocks-the-use-of-ssh?rq=1)

Comment: Your going to have to provide more details other then "it didn't work"

Comment: When I configure the ssh to run on port 443 and try to connect to it I get connection refused error.All the connection i.e web traffic goes through local proxy server(runs on port 8080) with trend internet security enabled.What other details  are required?